# STM32 Built-in LCD Controller Interface?

Tags: arm, stm32, lcd, peripheral

I have a bit of a specific question here:

I am the proud owner of an STM32L476 microcontroller. According to the [datasheet (page 41)](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/ed/2f/60/aa/79/42/0b/DM00108832.pdf/files/DM00108832.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108832.pdf), this specific MCU not only has a built-in LCD controller, but it can also drive an LCD in one of the built-in low-power modes. Problem is, I have no idea how to communicate with the LCD controller! I have scoured this datasheet and managed only to find the controller's memory address.

Does anyone know how to use this LCD controller?

P.S. I have searched the [programming manual](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/6c/3a/cb/e7/e4/ea/44/9b/DM00046982.pdf/files/DM00046982.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046982.pdf), but the word "LCD" doesn't appear once in the document. I really am at a total loss here

Comment: Maybe you should look at the sample software provided with the "
32L476GDISCOVERY" eval board which has a small LCD display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the Reference Manual, which covers peripherals. As you might have noticed, the Programming Manual only covers the core.

[RM0351 Reference Manual: STM32L4x6 advanced ARM-based 32-bit MCUs](http://www2.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00083560.pdf)

The LCD controller reference starts on page 658.

You should also check the application notes and examples thoroughly, since the Reference Manual usually only provides terse descriptions of the registers and their functions.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I guess you just have to know where to look

Comment: You should scour the whole Technical Documentation section in the product page for information. There are a lot of details scattered around.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/3d/e7/e4/13/2f/47/4d/e6/STM32L4_Peripheral_LCD.pdf/files/STM32L4_Peripheral_LCD.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_Peripheral_LCD.pdf) STM32L4 family LCD document.  It appears to have what is missing from the specific STM processor specification.

As processor manufacturers migrate toward intellectual property cores such as ARM and MIPS, they tend to also modularize/compartmentalize their documents.

Comment: And some of them have automated that mix-and-match process better than others...